# Read only queries Using ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to limit the application to read only queries. In other words, I want the application to process only those queries which are not changing the state of the database. I am using ADO.NET. I do not want to create a new user against the database with read only permissions. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new user?  That's the real way to do this, unless you have 100% control of the application code and can ensure that no data altering statements are executed through it.

Comment: The best, most secure, easiest way to do that is to limit the database user the application is using to readonly. There's even a built in role called `db_denydatawriter` which will automatically deny writing privileges for any database object from the user that has it.

Comment: The database is an external db and it does not allow to create a new database user (We don't have privileges to create a new database user). I am using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: SQL Authentication**

You can use connections as shown below:

```
Server ={serverName}; Initial Catalog = {DB_Name}; User Id={uid}; Password={pwd};
```

Use the uid which has only read access in database.

**Option 2: Windows Authentication**

If you want to use **Integrated Security = True;** (i.e. windows authentication) then you will have to grant readonly access to the windows user (under which the program runs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Application is using Windows Authentication and is running under the scope of an administrator (which is a Windows User). Administrator has all the privileges and we cannot change the permissions level. What if, the database even don't allow us to create a new database user with read only rights. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers  to cancel any insert update or delete through a trigger at the database level. The trigger would end with a rollback to cancel the transaction. You would have to figure out who kicked off the trigger so other users can update the db.

I would not do it - I would take away any permission (except select) from the account being used for the application. I have created many, many triggers but I have never heard anyone using database triggers to enforce read only.

Comment: Application is using Windows Authentication and is running 
 under the scope of an administrator. So, it has all the priveleges and can execute all the queries. The database is an external db and it doesn't allow us to create a new database user with read only permissions. Any thoughts on doing this without creating a new db user, changing the permission level of the existing Windows user.